# How to prevent producing to kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, aiven

We are debugging a bug and we need to prevent all producers to produce messages to a specific kafka-topic. There are alot of producers and I can't control them.

How can I do that on the kafka-side?

Answer (score 0):

Firewalling a port would block all traffic.

Setting up a TCP proxy and dropping packets would require a bit of work to understand the inner Kafka protocol.

Therefore, you would need to enable client authorization (SASL) or other authentication mechanisms on the broker(s), then modify certificates and/or ACL policies to limit server connections per topic

Refer `authorizer.class.name` config property

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security

Alternatively, topic quotas or `max.message.bytes` can be configured such that clients will be unable to send data, but they'll still be able to connect

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas

Comment: is `max.message.bytes` for producing or for consuming or for both?

Comment: It's a topic config, so both, but it only makes sense for producers because it limits how large any message batch can be https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_message.max.bytes